# Crossplatform multiclient oauth2 API design

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, cross-platform, google-oauth

I am building RESTfull backend with ASP.NET Web API 2.
FTM I have three *clients*: AngularJs web application, Android, and IPhone app.

I need to build login via Google and Facebook for all of them and need your help to design it.

My idea is the following (using Google auth as an example):

1. in Google Developer Console I create **4** "OAuth 2.0 client IDs":

   - for AngularJS app (type Web application, with allowed origins)
   - for Android (type Android)
   - for IOs (type IOs)
   - for WEB API backend (type Web application without any allowed origins)
2. every *client* will contact Google with its own libraries/apis to authorize and request User consent on the scopes needed **but also for offline use**. So that authorization_code is received by the *client* from Google.
3. every *client* will call web backend GET method ExternalLogin and send authorization_code as an input parameter.
4. web backend will exchange (via Google API) re authorization_code to the access_token and receive all needed User information from Google (via Google API). Check the database if User already registered (if not - app will create an account) and then issue **local access token** that should be used for all the further calls to web backend.

The benefits are pretty straightforward:

- simple flow, the same for every *client*
- a single method to login/register for every *client*
- the logic to collect User data is in one place (web backend) - so if We need extra data to collect from the User we need to make a change in the backend only. *Clients* need to add scopes to consent screen only.

My questions are:

- is the following flow correct and stable enough? Will it also work for Facebook auth?
- FTM I am stuck at step 4. AngularJs got authorization_code with its ClientId. Web backend is trying to exchange this authorization_code for access_token **with another ClientId** (web backend has its own ClientId in Google developer console, read above) I am getting an error: unauthorized_client. Strange, cause all ClientIDs in the same "Project" in google developer console. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Note: a user that auths with the client id from your AngualrJS app is not going to have access via Android.   Client id, secret, refresh token are a group they don't mix.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your comment. I need User to auth via Android/AngularJS/IOS ClientId then pass authorization_code to the backend and have access to Users data with Web-Backend ClientId and passed authorization_code. It won't work you think?

Comment: A refresh token created with web credentials is not going to be able to be refreshed using the credentials for a mobile application.     If you request access to a user using the Android/AngularJS/IOS  you will need to use the Android/AngularJS/IOS credentials to get the access.  You cant mix them just because they were created under the same project.

Comment: @z0omie But why do you think you should register 4 apps independently? I am not aware of mobile apps, but can't you just integrate OAuth in your WebAPI backend and let it handle all the token related part. And on all your clients, you will directly access the API endpoint which you have created for OAuth. By doing this your end-user doesn't have to authorize all your apps, which will improve the user experience as well. Eg - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-oauth-20-login-and-signup-in-sta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is pretty much ok, with one exception: you need to setup client IDs **only** for the actual client applications (hence the `Authorized JavaScript origins`), and not for the backend, too.

Facebook is pretty much the same on the backend side at least (just a different library for validation), you should have no problems abstracting away a generic provider interface.

As for validating the integrity of the ID token on the [server side](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) - do a GET on Google's endpoint to verify this token, let themworry about the validation algorithm:
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={0}`

Here's how this could look:

```cs
private const string GoogleApiTokenInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={0}";

public ProviderUserDetails GetUserDetails(string providerToken)
{
    var httpClient = new MonitoredHttpClient();
    var requestUri = new Uri(string.Format(GoogleApiTokenInfoUrl, providerToken));

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
    try
    {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var googleApiTokenInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleApiTokenInfo>(response);

    if (!SupportedClientsIds.Contains(googleApiTokenInfo.aud))
    {
        Log.WarnFormat("Google API Token Info aud field ({0}) not containing the required client id", googleApiTokenInfo.aud);
        return null;
    }

    return new ProviderUserDetails
    {
        Email = googleApiTokenInfo.email,
        FirstName = googleApiTokenInfo.given_name,
        LastName = googleApiTokenInfo.family_name,
        Locale = googleApiTokenInfo.locale,
        Name = googleApiTokenInfo.name,
        ProviderUserId = googleApiTokenInfo.sub
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) (renamed from [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/)). This will make it very easy for you and all you'll have to do is accept one token on your backend.

Please note that you don't need firebase database to use Firebase Auth.